# CherryPy server stopped when i run my Turbogear application

Tags: python, turbogears

When i run my application, it is getting stopped and reports the following error:

> ```
>  2012-06-16 02:40:51,767 turbogears.startup INFO Binding metadata for SQLAlchemy...
>  2012-06-16 02:40:51,785 cherrypy.error ERROR [16/Jun/2012:02:40:51] ENGINE Error in 'start' listener <function start_turbogears at 0x02CE2BF0>
>  Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cherrypy-3.2.2-py2.7-win32.egg\cherrypy\process\wspbus.py", line 197, in publish
>      output.append(listener(*args, **kwargs))
>    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\turbogears-1.5.1-py2.7.egg\turbogears\startup.py", line 201, in start_turbogears
>      database.bind_metadata()
>    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\turbogears-1.5.1-py2.7.egg\turbogears\database.py", line 80, in bind_metadata
>      metadata.bind = sqlalchemy.create_engine(dburi, **alch_args)
>    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.4.4-py2.7.egg\sqlalchemy\engine\__init__.py", line 160, in create_engine
>      return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
>    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.4.4-py2.7.egg\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 62, in create
>      dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
>    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy-0.4.4-py2.7.egg\sqlalchemy\databases\mysql.py", line 1420, in dbapi
>      import MySQLdb as mysql
>    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mysql_python-1.2.2-py2.5-win32.egg\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
>      import _mysql
>    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mysql_python-1.2.2-py2.5-win32.egg\_mysql.py", line 7, in <module>
>    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mysql_python-1.2.2-py2.5-win32.egg\_mysql.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
>  ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>
>  2012-06-16 02:40:51,845 cherrypy.error INFO [16/Jun/2012:02:40:51] ENGINE Started monitor thread 'Autoreloader'.
>  2012-06-16 02:40:51,854 cherrypy.error INFO [16/Jun/2012:02:40:51] ENGINE Started monitor thread '_TimeoutMonitor'.
>  2012-06-16 02:40:52,118 cherrypy.error INFO [16/Jun/2012:02:40:52] ENGINE Serving on 127.0.0.1:8087
>  2012-06-16 02:40:52,127 cherrypy.error ERROR [16/Jun/2012:02:40:52] ENGINE Shutting down due to error in start listener:
>  Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cherrypy-3.2.2-py2.7-win32.egg\cherrypy\process\wspbus.py", line 235, in start
>      self.publish('start')
>    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cherrypy-3.2.2-py2.7-win32.egg\cherrypy\process\wspbus.py", line 215, in publish
>      raise exc
>  ChannelFailures: ImportError('DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.',)
>
>  2012-06-16 02:40:52,161 cherrypy.error INFO [16/Jun/2012:02:40:52] ENGINE Bus STOPPING
>  2012-06-16 02:40:52,270 cherrypy.error INFO [16/Jun/2012:02:40:52] ENGINE HTTP Server cherrypy._cpwsgi_server.CPWSGIServer(('127.0.0.1', 8087)) shut down
>  2012-06-16 02:40:52,285 cherrypy.error INFO [16/Jun/2012:02:40:52] ENGINE Stopped thread '_TimeoutMonitor'.
>  2012-06-16 02:40:52,296 turbogears.startup INFO TurboGears has already been stopped.
>  2012-06-16 02:40:52,301 cherrypy.error INFO [16/Jun/2012:02:40:52] ENGINE Stopped thread 'Autoreloader'.
>  2012-06-16 02:40:52,308 cherrypy.error INFO [16/Jun/2012:02:40:52] ENGINE Bus STOPPED
>  2012-06-16 02:40:52,312 cherrypy.error INFO [16/Jun/2012:02:40:52] ENGINE Bus EXITING
>  2012-06-16 02:40:52,318 cherrypy.error INFO [16/Jun/2012:02:40:52] ENGINE Bus EXITED
>
>  System information:
>  OS: Windows 7, Python 2.7, Turbogears: 1.5.1, 
>  dev.cfg: sqlalchemy.dburi = 'mysql://root:mysql@localhost:3306/VistaDB'
> ```

What may be causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is "DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.'"

It is a mysql installation issue

Comment: I have created the database and insert some record manually in the MySql database.As soon as i specified the sqlalchemy.dburi parameter in my dev.cfg file,i am unable to start my application.Please guide me.

Comment: Thanks everyone, i just added easy_install mysql-python and mysql-python-1.2.3.win64-py2.7.exe. Everything got working.